# SQL Error - varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, varchar, alter-table

I imported a flat file into an SQL database and it created all of the fields as varchar(50).  I was able to change the data type of most fields, but hit an error in the weight field.  All of the data in the weight field is less than 6 characters in total length and is either a whole integer or a decimal.  I have tried both:

```
UPDATE MAWB
SET Weight = CAST(Weight AS decimal(12,2))
```

and:

```
ALTER TABLE MAWB
ALTER COLUMN [Weight] decimal(10,2)
```

I always get the error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I've checked that all of the fields are considered numeric using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MAWB
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Weight) = 0
```

I've also tried LTRIM and RTRIM just to be safe, but still get the error when I try to change the field.  Does anyone know what else might be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the offending rows with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM MAWB
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(12,2),Weight) IS NULL
AND Weight IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Nice catch, I missed the 2012 tag.

Comment: This helped.  Found that all of the offending fields were over 1,000 and therefore had commas.  Did a replace to remove those and then it converted over without issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So, [`ISNUMERIC()` is far from perfect](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html). It can return true for values like `e`, `$`, '€' and <kbd>tab</kbd>, and many others you wouldn't expect. But of course you can't convert those to every numeric type (`ISNUMERIC()` merely identifies that it can be converted to at least one of the numeric types). `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` won't help because they won't clear <kbd>tab</kbd> and other similar characters.

To identify rows which are really not numeric:

```
SELECT weight FROM dbo.table WHERE column NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%';
```

Or you can write a more elaborate scalar function, like the one in the link above, which handles more edge cases:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.isReallyNumeric  
(  
    @num VARCHAR(64)  
)  
RETURNS BIT  
BEGIN  
    IF LEFT(@num, 1) = '-'  
        SET @num = SUBSTRING(@num, 2, LEN(@num))  

    DECLARE @pos TINYINT  

    SET @pos = 1 + LEN(@num) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@num))  

    RETURN CASE  
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', @num) = 0  
        AND @num NOT IN ('.', '-', '+', '^') 
        AND LEN(@num)>0  
        AND @num NOT LIKE '%-%' 
        AND  
        (  
            ((@pos = LEN(@num)+1)  
            OR @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @num))  
        )  
    THEN  
        1  
    ELSE  
    0  
    END  
END  
GO
```

Once you've identified these rows and fixed the data, please, please, please fix the table too.